# Pointing a Makefile to a set of files of specific type

Tags: makefile, find, gnu-make

I'm writing my first Makefile...

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878383/create-rule-in-makefile-for-just-a-set-of-files) but I want to point the Makefile to a specific directory of .js and .css files.. how do you do this?

I have this so far:

```
JS_TARGETS = $(find path/to/js/ -name '*.js')
CSS_TARGETS = $(find path/to/css/ -name '*.css')

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

which doesn't work:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop.
```

Must be simple for someone who makes lots of Makefiles!  Thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wildcard` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Wildcard-Function):

```
JS_TARGETS  := $(wildcard path/to/js/*.js)
CSS_TARGETS := $(wildcard path/to/css/*.css)
```

Or, if for some reasons you have to use `find`, invoke it using [`shell` function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function) as follows:

```
JS_TARGETS  := $(shell find path/to/js/  -name '*.js')
CSS_TARGETS := $(shell find path/to/css/ -name '*.css')
```

However, the first way is preferable as more portable and fast.